# swift: AVSpeechUtterance long pause

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code to read my text:

```
var utterance = AVSpeechUtterance()
var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "\(textCount[modeIndex][0])")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
utterance.rate = 0.4
synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

But in my text I want do long pause after some words. How to do it? Maybe there are some symbol to do this (this `--` is not long)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechutterance#1668645

You are looking to split your utterance into multiple queued utterances, and use the `postUtteranceDelay`:

> **var postUtteranceDelay:** TimeInterval
>
> The amount of time a speech synthesizer will wait after the utterance is spoken before handling the next queued utterance.

Comment: I need to create pause in on text for example: `"My (long pause) pause"`. Not between like:` ["My", "pause"]`

Comment: This does not work for me. Could you give an example how to use this? I do something wrong.